# Spacing Issues between textboxs and expressions

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In the design everything look fine(pic 1), but when I preview the report, somehow there are the inconsistent gap between labels and expressions (pic 2); ex DOB. Some have more space, and some are very close to labels.

How can I fix the spacing issues?

[image]

[image]

Comment: reduce label width only this way you can do it. and place all in rectangle, this can also help sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it has to do with the anchoring of the various text boxes. When you move them about the report, you'll see anchoring lines and tooltips popping up that say "5px", etc. Some of those text boxes must have been inadvertantly anchored to other report items.

I'd suggest putting each row of report items into its own rectangle, see if that helps.